# Android Studio API Level warning not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having trouble, there is no warning when I use methods above API Level 8

```
setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

Is just an example

Even if I build my app there's no error, I'll only encounter the error when the app reaches the unsupported method.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just solve my problem

I just check the File > Settings > Inspections > Android Lint > "Calling new methods on older versions" because it's unchecked before

[image]