# Android Studio API level warning not showing on some newly added methods

Tags: android, android-studio

Note: There is a question with a similar title however this is not a duplicate. If you wonder what question that is: [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566221/android-studio-api-level-warning-not-showing) The option is already enabled in my IDE.

Recently we have updated an app with some bug fixes but one of the changes caused a critical crash, depending on a method that has been added in API 29, and Android Studio didn't warn me about it which led to an unavoidable crash at user base.

If you wonder, I also have API 29 documentation downloaded in IDE, so I can see the sources, javadocs in it.

The method I've used is [Parcel.writeBoolean(val)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#writeBoolean(boolean)) method. According to the documentation, this was added in API level 29 (I don't know why it's added this late but it was), however this is how it looks when I use it in the IDE. (Minimum API version is 21)

[image: Screenshot of the issue (no warnings)]

There are no warnings about the API usage. Hence I casually used it and it lead to a huge crash rate in our app.

Is there a way to check every method based on its API level? On normal cases (such as using `Context.getSystemService(Class clazz)` the IDE gives a warning that it is added in API level 23) it seems to be working, but on really newly added methods, it sometimes skips the warning.

Do I need to check every Android framework based method before using it? Or is there something that do this task properly? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I had an old version of Android Studio (3.5.1), updating it to 3.6.1 solved the issue.